# Scheme - Writing a bind function for association lists?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

I am trying to write a function in Scheme that simply creates an association list using `set!`.

The function will accept three parameters: the key, the value, and the association list and return the new association list. My code is as follows:

```
(define al '((A 1) (B 2) (C 3)))

(define (bind k v al)
    (cond
       ((null? al) set! al '((k v)))
       (else (set-car! al '(k v)))))
```

I want the code to work as follows:

**Existing Association List**: `((A 1) (B 2) (C 3))`

**Function Call:** `(bind D 4 al)`

**Output:** `((A 1) (B 2) (C 3) (D 4))`

But I get the error: `set!: bad syntax in: set!` on the first use of `set!`

How am I using `set!` incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the parentheses around the `set!` call:

```
(define (bind k v al)
    (cond 
        ((null? al) (set! al '((k v))))
        (else (set-car! al '(k v))))))
```

BTW, you have other problems:

1. `set!` is setting the local variable, not the global variable. Your function should return the new value of `al`. To use it, you need to do `(set! al (bind 'D 4 al))`. Also notice that you need to quote `D` when you call it, otherwise it will try to use the value of the variable `D`.
2. Variables aren't evaluated inside quoted lists. So you're putting the literal symbols `k` and `v` into the association list, not the values of those parameters.
3. `set-car!` will replace the first element of the list, not add a new element to the list. You need to use `cons` to add to the list.

The correct code should be:

```
(define (bind k v al)
    (cond 
        ((null? al) (set! al (list (list k v)))
        (else (set! al (cons (list k v) al))))
    al)
```

But consing onto an empty list is the same as creating a new list, so there's no need for the `null?` check; the two cases are the same. Just:

```
(define (bind k v al)
    (cons (list k v) al))
```

Comment: Is there a formatting error in your version of the bind function? It seems like you're missing a closing parentheses after the hanging 'al' on the last line.

Comment: Found it, it seems like you were missing a closing parentheses on the end of the first conditional

Comment: *always* `cons`ing the new value on `al`? What about if `k` is already set?

Comment: @user633183 Searching an alist returns the first match, so always consing works, and it's more time-efficient than searching for a match to update. It also allows for reverting a binding, by simply popping it off.

Comment: @Barmar clever! I hadn’t considered that. Thanks for the reply 